# 'text/paperscript' not recognized in webmatrix 3

Tags: javascript, html, webmatrix

I'm new to javascript and html and am trying to create a basic web page using paper.js. I have also read up about improving script loading times and implemented a fast inline script loader I found online. I have verified that the loader (using a popup box) makes it to the paper.js file. However, I try instantiating a paperscript script tag on the next line and webmatrix doesn't recognize it as a valid type parameter. Regardless, I tried loading a paperscript a similar way to the loader and it still didn't run the paperscript. The code should help explain better what I'm trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>  HTML Canvas  </title>
    </head>
     <body>

        <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="800" height="600">
            Canvas not supported.
        </canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function speedLoadJS(a,b){var c=document.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";if(c.readyState){c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(c.readyState=="loaded"||c.readyState=="complete"){c.onreadystatechange=null;b()}}}else{c.onload=function(){b()}}c.src=a;document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}
            function speedLoadPS(a,b,t){var c=document.createElement("script");c.type="text/paperscript";c.canvas=t;if(c.readyState){c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(c.readyState=="loaded"||c.readyState=="complete"){c.onreadystatechange=null;b()}}}else{c.onload=function(){b()}}c.src=a;document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">speedLoadJS("public/paper-full.min.js", function(){})</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">speedLoadPS("public/testDraw.js", function(){}, "mainCanvas")</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

testDraw.js is just the simple example on the paper.js website:

```
// Create a Paper.js Path to draw a line into it:
var path = new Path();
// Give the stroke a color
path.strokeColor = 'black';
var start = new Point(100, 100);
// Move to start and draw a line from there
path.moveTo(start);
// Note the plus operator on Point objects.
// PaperScript does that for us, and much more!
path.lineTo(start + [ 100, -50 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS (and IIS Express) require every mime type to be registered either in applicationHost.config or the web.config.  The text/paperscript mime type isn't registered, so it won't serve.  Check out this post on doing the same thing for LESS:

http://bob.yexley.net/using-less-css-with-visual-studio-and-iis-express/

Another post on a similar topic:

http://www.tomasmcguinness.com/2011/07/06/adding-support-for-svg-to-iis-express/

Happy coding!